# Nested struct definition

Tags: c, sim-card

I'm dealing with sim for computer architecture course. I try to compile package with MSYS1.1/MinGW with gcc v4.5.2.

Makelog:

```
    In file included from
    sim-outorder.c:107:0: bpred.h:214:5:
    error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint'
    ... 
    make: *** [sim-outorder.o] Error 1
```

I checked the line 214 in bpred.h, there is a nested struct definition as:

```
208 /* branch predictor update information */ 
209 struct bpred_update { 
210 char *pdir1;         /* direction-1 predictor counter */ 
211 char *pdir2;         /* direction-2 predictor counter */ 
212 char *pmeta;  /* meta predictor counter */ 
213 struct dir{             /* predicted directions */ 
214  uint bimod  : 1;    /* bimodal predictor */ 
215  uint twolev : 1;    /* 2-level predictor */ 
216  uint meta   : 1;    /* meta predictor (0..bimod / 1..2lev) */ 
217 } dir; 
218 };
```

What's wrong with this struct block?
Could you please help??
Thanks!

Comment: Where is `uint` defined?

Comment: struct unsigned int uint; added, case is solved. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are disallowed from naming the inner struct:

```
208 /* branch predictor update information */ 
209 struct bpred_update { 
210 char *pdir1;         /* direction-1 predictor counter */ 
211 char *pdir2;         /* direction-2 predictor counter */ 
212 char *pmeta;  /* meta predictor counter */ 
213 struct     {             /* predicted directions */  
/******    ^^^^ --- NO NAME HERE -- THIS IS WHAT YOU MUST CHANGE */
214  uint bimod  : 1;    /* bimodal predictor */ 
215  uint twolev : 1;    /* 2-level predictor */ 
216  uint meta   : 1;    /* meta predictor (0..bimod / 1..2lev) */ 
217 } dir; 
218 };
```

I suspect this because a "specifier-qualifier-list" sounds like a token which is part of something like `struct dim = {0};`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, inner structs are not allowed to have names, this is due to how you need to reference structures in C normally:

```
struct A {
   ...
};

struct B {
    struct A my_a;
};
```

It is thus unclear to a naive C compiler if it is should be expecting a variable, or a type declaration.

This is a case where however, using a c++ compiler it would work as you expect it to, due to the fact C++ does not expect the struct prefix for variable decelerations.

The solution is to either remove the name from the inner struct, or declare it outside of the other struct.

Comment: this problem is specific to any g++ version? i check the package, it seems like there is no need to move inner struct out. >dir_update_ptr->dir.meta  = (*meta >= 2);

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow your question... First of all, the original question is about C, not C++, g++ is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. Additionally, what do you mean that there is no need to move the inner struct out? Weren't you getting a compiler error? Anyways, that was just one of two options to resolve the original compiler error.

Comment: why can't you have named struct in another struct?